# Default path for iOS SDK Home does not appear in Titanium Studio

Tags: ios, sdk, titanium, filepath, home-directory

I'm trying to set up Titanium Studio in a MAC machine. I got the followings installed.

- Titanium Studio - 3.2.3
- Xcode 5.1.1

But in the location where the path to iOS SDK Home has to be given, it appears as "Not specified".

I have the 2 options, "Refresh" and "Update". Refreshing does not give any result and when I click on "Update" it says no updates are available.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Titanium Studio dashboard?

Comment: Also check whether your system meets http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix

Comment: Thanks for your information @Anand. Except for Node.js all the other system requirements are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following from Appcelerator Q&A

> It might be the run configurations that have had their iOS version
>   blanked out. If you edit the run configuration that you are compiling
>   under, you should hopefully see that there is nothing set in the iOS
>   version. Set the value to what you want.

reference : [iOS7 SDK not found](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160722/updated-to-320-ios-7-sdk-not-found-among-many-other-broken-things)

Hope it helped you!!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it has anything to do with run configuration. I have installed Titanium Studio in few MAC machines before and never came across such issue. However, I was able to resolve it by re-installing Titanium Studio. Thanks @Anand.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ti setup` or `appc setup` command (recommended) in terminal it will configure everything required

Answer (score 0):

Check the node version:

> node -v

AppCelerator is currently NOT compatible with node v6.x, use Node Version Manager : https://github.com/creationix/nvm